# C# Delete DLL file with full permission get Unauthorized exception

Tags: c#, dll, tfs, directoryinfo, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm trying to delete all file from `destBackUpFolder`, the result is all files are deleted from the folder **except 1 dll file**, I get a **Unauthorized Exception** said that **access to the dll file is denied**. I have tried suggestion from web by setting the file attribute to normal and delete file by file, check my permission and make sure my permission is allowed to delete file but all those method doesn't work, Why am I getting unauthorized exception even my permission is set to full control? FYI, I am using **Team Foundation Server** for my development version control, Is the problem here related to my TFS? Thanks in advance.

```
try
{
    DirectoryInfo folderToBeDelete = new DirectoryInfo(destBackUpFolder);
    folderToBeDelete.Delete(true);

    if (Directory.Exists(backupFolder))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destBackUpFolder);
        result = CopyFileAndFolder(backupFolder, destBackUpFolder);

        if (result)
        {
            ErrorMsg = "Copy process Failed,Your File has rolled back to previous version";
            IsErrorDetected = true;
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception)
{
    ErrorMsg = "Error during roll up process";
    IsErrorDetected = true;
}
    //block of code where i trying to get my version number of the dll 
      Assembly _assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DllPathForBackUp"]);
        Version versionNumber = _assembly.GetName().Version;
        completeVersionNumber = versionNumber.Major + "." + versionNumber.Minor + "." + versionNumber.Build + "." + versionNumber.Revision;
```

Comment: Perhaps the dll is in use? Does your system allow you to delete the dll manually?

Comment: thanks for fast reply, i cant delete the dll manually as well, i got the message say that the dll is in use. How to check which process is using my dll in this case.

Comment: Have a look at Process Explorer: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processexplorer.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Manually or programmatically?

Comment: Hi there, i found the cause, the dll file is used by a exe file from Microsoft Visual Studio devenv.exe, when i tried to delete the dll file, i cant access the dll file due to the devenv.exe, is there anyway i can unlock the file from devenv.exe?

Comment: By the sounds of it you're trying to delete a dll that your currently running app is referencing. Is that the case? Because there's no way you're going to be able to do that.

Comment: to be more specific, i planned to get the version number of the dll file before i tried to delete it, is this the cause where the devenv.exe lock my dll file? Below is my code to get the version number

Comment: You might want to investigate MOVEFILE_DELAY_UNTIL_REBOOT in the MoveFileEx function. Essentially it marks the file to be moved /deleted on reboot:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365240(VS.85).aspx

Comment: If your app was looking at the dll to get information, it could be that it still had the file in use. Can you delete the dll manually when your app is not running?

Comment: yes when my app is not running i can delete the dll.

Comment: okay is confirm now,i have test it manually, when my program execute until the line  Assembly _assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DllPathForBackUp"]); i cannot delete my dll until the program terminates, is there anyway i could unlock the file after i get the dll information?

Comment: Sir thank you for your help, i use a different way to get the info from dll which is  FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DllPathForBackUp"]).FileVersion, with this way i don't have to load the dll file into my program and get the exception, Sir i am sincerely grateful for your help as i am new to c# programming, your advice has enlighten me, thank you for your time and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i was using the dll when i loaded the dll into my program with

```
 Assembly _assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DllPathForBackUp"]);
```

i change this code to

```
FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DllPathForBackUp"]).FileVersion;
```

Now i dont have to load the dll into the program and get the error, Credit to  @Darren Gourley, Thank you!